# What do the '=' and ';' characters mean in a .bat file?

Tags: batch-file, dos

The following .bat file does not produce an error. Why?

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
:::::::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
===============
=;=;=;=;=;=;=;=
;=;=;=;=;=;=;=;
```

I know the '@' line prefix means "do not echo" and the `::` prefix means "this is a comment", but what do the `;` and `=` do?

As far as I can tell you can start a line with any mixture of ';' and '=' symbols and it has no effect whatsoever. `=;=;=;=;=;=dir` does execute `dir`. What is the correct interpretation of '=' and ';' ?

Comment: Excuse me, but :: does NOT mean comment. A colon precede a label, but a label that start with colon can not be used, so the command processor ignores it. The use of :: for lines with comments is customary and the same effect can be obtained with other characters that can not be included in a label, like :/ :\ :. etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are interpreted as command line delimiters (along with a comma and white-space characters) so the following are all equivalent;

```
dir c:\ /b
dir c:\;/b
dir c:\=/b
dir c:\,/b
```

In the case of `=;=;=;=;=;=dir` they are presumably treated as leading white-space and ignored

Comment: Thanks for including ',' as a possibility too.

Answer (score 1):

example

```
   ;;for;=/l=%%^^;in;,=;(;;0;=,=1,% hello% 5::@loop)=,=do;;@echo(%%^^%
```